# bizzare nullable decimal precision behavior

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, precision

I have some columns in a data store using 12 decimal precision.

I want to round it to 4 places for the purpose of sending it off via text feed, and the consumers of that feed need x precision.

**I am using a custom built workflow engine, and don't have direct access to the code at any point of execution**, but can inject code on any field using conditons for example:

```
if (obj.myValue.HasValue)
    obj.myValue = System.Math.Round(obj.MyValue.Value, 4)
```

the above example works in doing the rounding, but in **SOME** cases does not remove the trailing 0's. The end result automatically generated using obj.myValue.ToString() (and so on, for all the fields)

This seems to happen only on nullable decimal fields.

I am not sure what is different but in about 10% of the rows, the output retains trailing 0's. The actual value IS rounded, but 0s stay:

```
134.402100000000
```

I also tried doing it this way (just to be sure and remove the initial precision of the decimal)

```
if (obj.myValue.HasValue)
    obj.myValue = decimal.Parse(obj.MyValue.Value.ToString("#.####"))
```

again, SOME rows remain with appended trailing 0s.

It almost looks like the property is initialized to x decimal places, and final ToString.

Considering i do not have direct access of this code, but can inject any c# to be performed on that property, are there any other things I could try? (I also tried hard coding all rows to a value, and that works fine w/out extra 0s)

also interesting is that i can't reproduce this behavior in my tests..

```
        decimal d1 = 160236194.3900000000000001M;
        Console.WriteLine(d1);
        d1 = Math.Round(d1, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(d1);

160236194.3900000000000001
160236194.3900
Press any key to continue . . .
```

edit

tried another approach thanks to e.James (testing to see if truncate would remove the 0s)

```
if (obj.myValue.HasValue)
    obj.myValue = decimal.Truncate(obj.MyValue.Value)
```

and.. truncation works on all rows, but 0s still stay on those that had the previously! The difference is that this time it is only 0s.. before truncating it was .8900000000 etc.. This is wild!

Comment: Un-binary-representable floats should be a major FAQ entry up here somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some decimal numbers can not be perfectly represented in binary format. Your `obj.myValue` property is a decimal number. For certain decimals, it simply will not be able to store anything other than (for example) 1234.4021000000000001, which is as close as it can be with a limited number of bits.

I think Domenic has the right idea with his answer. Let decimal numbers remain un-rounded in storage, and only display* them rounded off.

If you absolutely *must* have the numbers rounded in storage, you will have to use an integer format, which you then divide by 1000 prior to display. 1234.4021 would be stored as 12344021.

*note: by "display" I mean "output to text", not necessarily "show to a user"

Comment: yes, it appears to be the case here.. but how can i round that 000000001  into 4 decimal places? truncation or converting to int is the only way?

Comment: I think truncation would be the best way. That 00000001 is already rounded as far as it can be, so doing anything mathematical with it will not help.

Comment: what is also interesting is that i can't reproduce this in my tests.. Math.Round seems to always work..

Comment: What type of value does Math.Round return? Could it be a double-precision float, while `obj.myValue` is a single-precision float?

Comment: Also, how are you testing Math.Round()? (Math.Round(1234.40211111, 4) == 1234.4021) would still evaluate to true, since *both* would be stored as 1234.4021000000001

Comment: well.. myValue is a decimal, and Math.Round takes/returns decimal. BUT the initial value in the data store IS a single-precision float

Comment: you may be onto something.. that the conversion problem is between single and double precision float....

Comment: but. none of this still explains why the 2nd approach doesn't work :)    val = decimal.parse(val.ToString("#.####"))

Comment: What does `decimal.parse()` return? I'll bet it returns a decimal number, which takes us back to the same problem. There is simply no way to store 1234.4021 *exactly* in a double precision float. The closest thing you *can* store is 1234.402100000000001, so that's what you get. The only way around it is to change your storage format. You can store in an integer, as I describe above, or you can store a string of characters. As soon as you store the value in floating point format, you will run into floating point precision issues for some numbers. Base 2 can not map to base 10 for all numbers!

Comment: decimal.parse is fine. as a test i was assigning that to a string (comment) field, and the 0s were gone. I just noticed that the issue is happening only on nullable decimal fields.. it possible the nullable type stores some extra info about its value.. and that info is not being re-set when the value is re-assigned?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but I have no idea what would be going on behind the scenes in that case. If you ever do figure out what happened, please leave a note here! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Why not let the display logic handle the, uh, display logic? That is, only when you go to display the `decimal` as a `string` should you care about the number of trailing `0`s displayed, in which case you should use `theDecimal.ToString("#.####")`.

Comment: did i mention that the data would be uh displayed? nope. it is generated as a feed. and as per my post, i already tried this approach

Comment: if it's not being displayed, then why are you worried about trailing 0s? They are purely a display artifact.

Comment: because it is a file based feed, and the consumers of that feed care. and no, i can't tell them to stop caring.

Comment: So you are displaying it, in a file? Well then, when you write it to the file that's when you do the string conversion...

Comment: As e.James alludes to, when we make the separation between "display logic" and the rest of the program, display doesn't imply a UI.

Comment: i don't have access to file generation code. as my post states, i dont have access at any point of execution accept for workflow.